# HBase application: Unit testing by mocking the HBase

Tags: unit-testing, junit, hbase, mockito, powermock

I have a method  in my application which is accessing data from HBase. It uses scan method to query hbase. I want to write unit test cases for testing this function. So I want to mock the hbase calls. How to do it? I am using Mockit for mocking.

Comment: Are you trying to test the actual querying or are you trying to mock the query so you can test parts of your application that uses the queried data?

Comment: I want to test the service method which does operations on the data returned from HBase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Mockito, you can stub your classes to make them return what you want.

Let's say you had a class called `HBaseHelper` and a method called `getData()` within the class that used a scanner to retrieve data from hbase. Now let's say you have another method called `useData()` in another class as such:

```
public String useData() {
  String data = hbaseHelper.getData();

  // ... Do things with data
  return data;
}
```

If you are using Mockito, you can effectively do something like this inside your test to return dummy 'data' and test the method that uses this data:

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@Mock
HBaseHelper hbaseHelper;

@Test
public void testFoo() {
  when(hbaseHelper.getData()).thenReturn("hello world");

  assertThat(useData()).equals("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Xinzz. I am trying to do similar stuff. But my HBaseHelper have static methods and static block. So it is trying to connect to actual HBase in its static block. so How do I mock the static method calls.

Comment: It's typically bad design if you have to mock static methods. However, if you REALLY need to, checkout PowerMockito[https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage], specifically `PowerMockito.mockStatic()`

Comment: I did it with power mock. But is it bad to have static methods in Util class, where I get hbase table and retrieve the data and return.

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can use [`HBaseTestingUtility`](https://hbase.apache.org/testapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseTestingUtility.html) like this:

```
private static final HBaseTestingUtility TEST_UTIL =
  new HBaseTestingUtility();

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
TEST_UTIL.getConfiguration().setBoolean("hbase.table.sanity.checks", false);
TEST_UTIL.startMiniCluster();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
TEST_UTIL.shutdownMiniCluster();
EnvironmentEdgeManager.reset();
}
```

Additionally you may need **Thrift server** to use some client libs:

```
private static final HBaseTestingUtility TEST_UTIL =
  new HBaseTestingUtility();

ThriftServer thriftServer;
Thread thriftServerThread;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
TEST_UTIL.getConfiguration().setBoolean("hbase.table.sanity.checks", false);
TEST_UTIL.startMiniCluster();

List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
port = HBaseTestingUtility.randomFreePort();
args.add("-" + ThriftServer.PORT_OPTION);
args.add(String.valueOf(port));
args.add("-infoport");
int infoPort = HBaseTestingUtility.randomFreePort();
args.add(String.valueOf(infoPort));
args.add("start");

thriftServer = new ThriftServer(TEST_UTIL.getConfiguration());

thriftServerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    thriftServer.doMain(args.toArray(new String[args.size()]));
  }
});
thriftServerThread.setDaemon(true)
thriftServerThread.start();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
TEST_UTIL.shutdownMiniCluster();
EnvironmentEdgeManager.reset();
}
```

With **pyspark** through py4j this way:

```
def setUp(self):
    super(StreamingTest, self).setUp()

    # --- hbase configuration ---
    hbase_testing_utility_clz = self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() \
        .loadClass('org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility')
    self._hbaseTestingUtility = hbase_testing_utility_clz.newInstance()

    self._hbaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster()


def tearDown(self):
    if self._hbaseTestingUtility is not None:
        self._hbaseTestingUtility.shutdownMiniCluster()
```

and if **Thrift server** is needed (for example to use [`happybase`](https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) client lib):

```
def setUp(self):
    super(StreamingTest, self).setUp()

    # --- hbase configuration ---
    hbase_testing_utility_clz = self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() \
        .loadClass('org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility')
    self._hbaseTestingUtility = hbase_testing_utility_clz.newInstance()
    self._hbaseTestingUtility.getConfiguration().setBoolean("hbase.table.sanity.checks", False)  # for thrift
    self._hbaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster()

    # --- thrift server configuration ---
    thrift_server_clz = self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() \
        .loadClass('org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer')

    # make thrift server instance
    cArgs = self.sparkStreamingContext.sparkContext._gateway.new_array(self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Class, 1)
    cArgs[0] = self._hbaseTestingUtility.getConfiguration().getClass()
    iArgs = self.sparkStreamingContext.sparkContext._gateway.new_array(self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Object, 1)
    iArgs[0] = self._hbaseTestingUtility.getConfiguration()

    self._thriftServer = thrift_server_clz\
        .getDeclaredConstructor(cArgs)\
        .newInstance(iArgs)

    # prepare server start arguments
    tArgs = self.sparkStreamingContext.sparkContext._gateway.new_array(self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.String, 5)
    port = self._hbaseTestingUtility.randomFreePort()
    self.thrift_port = port
    tArgs[0] = "-port"
    tArgs[1] = str(port)
    tArgs[2] = "-infoport"
    info_port = self._hbaseTestingUtility.randomFreePort()
    tArgs[3] = str(info_port)
    tArgs[4] = "start"

    mArgs = self.sparkStreamingContext.sparkContext._gateway.new_array(self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Class, 1)
    mArgs[0] = tArgs.getClass()
    method = thrift_server_clz.getDeclaredMethod('doMain', mArgs)
    method.setAccessible(True)

    args = self.sparkStreamingContext.sparkContext._gateway.new_array(self.sparkStreamingContext._jvm.java.lang.Object, 1)

    # start server in separate thread
    args[0] = tArgs
    self.thrift_server_thread = threading.Thread(target=method.invoke, args=[self._thriftServer, args])
    self.thrift_server_thread.setDaemon(True)
    self.thrift_server_thread.start()
```

of course hbase and thrift jars should be passed trough spark submit:

```
--jars path/to/jar1.jar,path/to/jar2.jar, --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true
```

Comment: Thanks!, btw, in thrift server java mock, I think cmdLineThread.start() should be thriftServerThread.start()  also you have to use reflection in order to do so

Comment: BiS, thank you for comment. Fixed. Reflection was used by Spark developers and i did the same.